# What is the correct way to scale images inside of a PICTURE tag?

Tags: html, css

Scaling images is easy.

```
.container > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately scaling `source` inside of a `picture` tag in a similar way doesn't work.

```
.container > source {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

What is the correct way to scale images inside of a `<picture>` tag?

In the example below how would I scale these 2 images to the browser width?

```
<div class="container">
     <picture>
        <source srcset="first-image.webp" type="image/webp">
        <img src="second-image.jpg"> 
     </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you oversimplified the HTML examples in your question; the picture contains only one img, but you say "these 2 images". So I hope this will work for you.

The solution is to not try to target the source, but just the img. You do need to write the selector correctly though.

```css
.container > picture > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <picture>
        <source srcset="first-image.webp" type="image/webp">
        <img src="second-image.jpg"> 
     </picture>
</div>
```

By the way, it's more semantic to use `<figure>` here instead of `<div class="container">`.

Comment: You are 100% correct!  I had been testing with a child selector `.container >  img` but it should have been `.container img` or the way you wrote it `.container > picture > img`.

Answer (score 0):

well you can user media element like

media="(min-width: 650px)" in source

source - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: That loads different pictures based on screen width but it doesn't scale them to the browser width.